# Panel.GroupingText in ContenPlaceholder shows first in all Panels

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

On my asp webforms page I have code similar to this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnltest1" runat="server" GroupingText="Panel1">
        Panel 1
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnltest2" runat="server" GroupingText="Panel2">
        Panel 2
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

The problem is that in both fieldsets the legend-tag has the text of the first panel groupingtext ("Panel 1").
If I test it without the use of a master page all is correct.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: http://tinyurl.com/no649wx (empty default masterpage-template of visual-studio) Since you've mentioned that this is just "similar" to your code, the issue must be caused by something that you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim I have found the error. I was focusing on web-controls while the error was in bad coded javascript.
The following line of javascript produced the error:

```
$('legend').html('<span>' + $('legend').html() + '</span>');
```

After changing it to

```
$('legend').each(function () {
        $(this).html('<span>' + $(this).html() + '</span>');
    });
```

all is working fine again.